# MomentJS sometimes returns invalid dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
data.begin="16-12-2014 4:00 PM"
data.begin=moment(data.begin, "DD-MM-YYYY h:mm A"); 
data.begin=parseInt(moment.utc(data.begin).valueOf());
```

and then I'm saving this in my database. The value stored in database is `1418725800000`.

I'm displaying the same in my form using the following code

```
return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm A');
```

It is showing the correct data, but sometimes when I try the same, I'm getting `Invalid date` error. What is the issue here?

I'm getting errors while saving and displaying this data in my app, sometimes it is showing wrong date wometimes wrong time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error screenshot, you're trying to parse miliseconds since epoch start as `String`:

```
moment("1418725800000")...
```

Instead, you should use a `Number`:

```
moment(1418725800000)...
```

Maybe you're having the same problem in other places. Use `parseInt(string, 10)` to transform a `String` to `Number`, e.g. when using a value from an `<input>`.